# Why does my raster file size increase after aggregating/cropping?

Tags: r, geospatial, filesize, r-raster

I am working with a NETcdf files on air pollution. Monthly data is stored in .nc files, which span over the entire North America, in a resolution of 0.01*0.01. However, I only need the data for US, at a resolution of 0.5.
So I do the following:

1. crop the data using USA boundaries: `raster::mask(raster::crop(PM25, raster::extent(USA)),USA)`
2. Aggregate the data: `aggregate(PM25, fact = 50)`

However, the file size of my raster increases tremendously after each of these two steps. I also tried to first aggregate and then crop the raster. But in this case, the file size first increases and then deceases slightly after cropping.

Any ideas why this is happening? Large file sizes are a big problem because I have over 100 files on which I need to perform the above operations in a loop.

Any help/advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow with a good question. You might include in your above dim of your PM25. Not directly addressing the problem, but some good reads on what is going on [Processing Large Rasters](https://strimas.com/post/processing-large-rasters-in-r/) . Is the PM25 data already available in 0.5 resolution? There are much better raster experts than me who will assist. Have you tried this under the R pkg `terra`?

Answer (score 0):

If what you refer to as "file size" is actually the size of the *R* object, the explanation is probably that `PM25` has its values on disk (in a file) while the `RasterBrick` with the aggregated values has its values in RAM memory. If you are concerned about running out of RAM you could instead write the values to file by using a `filename` argument like this

```
aggregate(PM25, fact = 50, filename="agg1.tif")
```

There is a (perhaps small) performance penalty for writing to disk.

Also, I would think that you ought to first use `aggregate`, and then use  `mask` to avoid edge effects.